# Read/Write distribution over MySQL Master/Slaves using Dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, dapper

Would dapper have any problems with using two IDbConnection objects for distributing Writes and Reads between MySQL Master/Slaves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not at all.

Dapper's identity cache uses the connection string as part of the key. This means you could even have your tables "out-of-column-order" in both the master and slave, and dapper would cope fine with it.